# Tag users' feelings in Facebook share dialogs

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

I was wondering if there is any way to tag the user feelings when he's sharing content.

For example: tag him ahead as playing a game/ reading something etc. 
[image: expected result]
 [image]

Comment: There's no API for that unfortunately.

Comment: that's a shame :/ they should add it to the new API